# Android app ActionBar got covered by white rectangle after refreshing the question

Tags: bug, android-app

I noticed that the Android app has been updated with new pull down to refresh animations inside questions, but I noticed a glitch when I made these steps:

- open notifications drawer from the right
- select an answer on my question inside my notifications
- go to the top and do the pull down refresh

The result is this:

[image: glitch]

Info: Nexus 5, running stock Android 4.4.4

Comment: You're correct to report it here, but I couldn't repro the issue. Was it affecting all your notifications/answer-notifications only/this particular question?

Comment: @Andrew it happens on every question. Just try pulling down to refresh multiple times, it even happens on this particular question

Comment: Repro'd on 1.0.51.

Comment: Not repro anymore on v1.0.83, but I'm not sure if it's fixed, or it's Android version dependent (not repro on Marshmallow, but couldn't test for pre-Lollipop)

Comment: Meanwhile, I'm using a different phone than mentioned in OP. It's an Xperia Z5 running 5.0.1. I can't reproduce this anymore.